# Cannot display images in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create a gallery page but cannot display images where the images are stored in a directory and the image details are stored in the database, below is my image create action:

```
public ActionResult Create(ImagesVM img, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var filename = "";
            var path = "";
            if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + img.PlayerId)))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + img.PlayerId));
                }
                var ext = upload.ContentType.ToString();
                ext = ext.Substring(ext.LastIndexOf('/') + 1).ToString();
                filename = img.PlayerId.ToString() + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "." + ext;
                path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + img.PlayerId.ToString() + "/" + filename);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("error", "There was an error with saving the record");
                img.Players = new SelectList(db.Players, "Id", "Name");
                return View(img);
            }

            upload.SaveAs(path);
            ImageDTO dto = new ImageDTO();
            dto.ImageName = filename;
            dto.ImageUrl = path;
            dto.ThumbnailTitle = img.ThumbnailTitle;
            dto.ThumbnailDetails = img.ThumbnailDetails;
            dto.PlayerId = img.PlayerId;
            db.Images.Add(dto);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        img.Players = new SelectList(db.Players, "Id", "Name");
        return View(img);

    }
```

Here is the index view where I want to display the images:

```
@model IEnumerable<CricketNew.Models.Data.ImageDTO>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
var imgPath = "~/Images/";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>


<div class="container">
    <h2>Image Gallery</h2>
    <p>The .thumbnail class can be used to display an image gallery.</p>
    <p>The .caption class adds proper padding and a dark grey color to text 
inside thumbnails.</p>
    <p>Click on the images to enlarge them.</p>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="@(imgPath + item.PlayerId + "/" + item.ImageName)" target="_blank">
                    <img src="@(imgPath + item.PlayerId + "/" + item.ImageName)" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum donec id elit non mi porta gravida at 
eget metus.</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

I tried different ways like below:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(imgPath + item.PlayerId + "/" + item.ImageName)" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">  
//this gives output like /Views/Images/Photos/1/abc.jpeg

<img src="@Url.Content(item.ImageUrl)" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">  
//this gives output like D:/Projects/Cricket/Views/Images/Photos/1/abc.jpeg

<img src="@(imgPath + item.PlayerId + "/" + item.ImageName)" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">  
//this gives output like D:/Projects/Cricket/Views/Images/Photos/1/abc.jpeg
```

Here is the output that I get from the index action:

[image]

but I could not load the images properly, your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Describe what _"could not load the images properly"_ means? Are there error messages? What are the different ways you tried? I also spot differences in the way "Photos" is spelled in the paths.

Comment: @Jasen : I edited the question and rectified the errors you spotted.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is it a 404 error? A 500 error? Something else? We're not there to look over your shoulder so it's hard for us to diagnose. Have you verified the files exists and the application has permission to access these directories?

Comment: @Jasen : No I do not get any error but the images are not displayed, I mean the images cannot be located, let me add a screenshot of the output page.

Comment: Use the browser's developer console which will display errors.

Comment: @Jasen : There it says that failed to load the resource with name 6_44a0fba6-6f22-4ae6-a912-e67fde64a19a.jpeg

Comment: With the Code `Server.MapPath("~/Views/Images/Photos/" + img.PlayerId.ToString() + "/" + filename);` you are generating a path like this :

"C:\projectlocation\Views\Images\Photos\FileName" 

instead the ImageUrl path should look like this "/Views/Images/Photos/FileName" in order to display the image....

Comment: @Aldo : I have tried both ways which are listed in my question.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should save the images in image folder in root of website  not in views folder .
because the contents of  views folder is forbidden to access from public .

Comment: I tried this but when I create the directories through the code then they are shown grey out in the solution explorer and hence the images inside these directories are not displayed, but when I manually created directory and added a picture there then it was displayed properly.

Comment: I want to create the directory for each player id dynamically, because it is unknown how many players will be added/deleted so directory creation and deletion depends on the players added to the db.

Comment: i understand so  no problem to create directory in images folder dynamically  for every player  and upload file .